# Strange behaviour when adding day on Date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to add some day on a date but actually i got a strange result...

I test with today as current day (28/02/2019), and try to add like 400 day and I'm in year 2096... I think tere is a problem

Take a look at my function :

```js
const user = { LastReport: new Date(), Validite: "413" }

var temp = new Date(user.LastReport)
console.log("Current : " + temp);
user.DateValide = temp.setDate(temp.getDate() + user.Validite);
console.log("Day to add : " + user.Validite)
console.log("Result : " + new Date(user.DateValide))
```

and my result :

[image]

There is something i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: ..... Yes a saw a lot of topic about add a day on a date. But actually my code look like the same as the others topic and it still don't works

Comment: I've created a snippet. Seems to work fine

Comment: @adiga Lol, how can it append ? seriously

Comment: Aha `413` is a string. Check the answer posted. Please create a [mcve] from next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `temp.getDate() + user.Validite` are being concatenated as strings so the days added is `28413` instead of `441`.

Use `parseInt()` to convert them to Number or you can prefix them with an arithmetic operator like `+`.

```js
const user = { LastReport: new Date(), Validite: "413" }

var temp = new Date(user.LastReport)
console.log("Current : " + temp);
//user.DateValide = temp.setDate(parseInt(temp.getDate()) + parseInt(user.Validite));
user.DateValide = temp.setDate(+temp.getDate() + +user.Validite);
console.log("Day to add : " + user.Validite)
console.log("Result : " + new Date(user.DateValide))
```

Comment: In ECMAScript, the '+' character is overloaded and has three possible meanings. When used like `+ +user.Validite`, the first is seen as the [*addition operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus), the second is seen as the [*unary + operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator). :-)